# javascript: how can I extract the values entered in this form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

This is not working for me. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
function showValues() {
  var uIwD;
  uIwD = document.getElementById(uInputs.fWD);
  alert ("You entered: " + uIwD);
}
```

```html
<form id="uInputs">
  Enter a value in the first field, then press Submit:<br>

  <input type="number" id="fWD" value="" min="0" max ="6">
  Weekday (0 to 6 for Sun to Sat)<br>

  <input type="number" name="fHr" value="" min="0" max ="23">
  Hour (0 to 23)<br>

  <input type="number" name="fMins" value="" min="0" max ="59">
  Minutes (0 to 59)<br>

  <input type="number" name="fSecs" value="" min="0" max ="59">
  Seconds (0 to 59)<br>

  <input type="number" name="fWOffset" value="-6" min="-12" max ="12">
  wOffsetHours (-12 to 12)<br>

  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="showValues()">
</form>
```

I enter a value of 3 in the first input field, then I click "Submit" and I get a js alert popup saying "You entered: null"

I have tried replacing name= with ID= in the first input field, and then using just that ID in GetElementbyID(), but the result is the same.

[Here](http://moongazer.x10.mx/website/try/) is a working page where you can see the result. (I tried making a fiddle for it, but when I run it in jsfiddle, I get no alert message at all. It would seem js alert pop-ups don't work in jsfiddle.)

Comment: Variable `uInputs` is undefined. `documents.getElementById` takes a string parameter with the element ID you're looking for, e.g. `document.getElementById('fWD')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing it wrong. id should be a string and then you can access the Childs with id's as  properties.

For example to test the first input box

```js
  function showValues() {
    var uIwD;
    var uIwD = document.getElementById("uInputs");
    alert ("You entered: " + uIwD.fWD.value);
    }
```

```html
</head>
<body>

 <form id="uInputs">
 Enter a value in the first field, then press Submit:<br>

 <input type="number" id="fWD" value="" min="0" max ="6">
 Weekday (0 to 6 for Sun to Sat)<br>

 <input type="number" name="fHr" value="" min="0" max ="23">
 Hour (0 to 23)<br>

 <input type="number" name="fMins" value="" min="0" max ="59">
 Minutes (0 to 59)<br>

 <input type="number" name="fSecs" value="" min="0" max ="59">
 Seconds (0 to 59)<br>

 <input type="number" name="fWOffset" value="-6" min="-12" max ="12">
 wOffsetHours (-12 to 12)<br>

 <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="showValues()">
 </form>
```

Comment: Ure, thanks for that answer. It worked for me in the sense that I could retrieve the values, but it has now raised another question: When retrieved that way, can I treat the values as numeric? Some results I'm getting when attempting to use the values, suggest that I can't. Is there something further I need to do to convert them to numeric values?

Comment: Yes something like this parseInt(uIwD.fWD.value)